# Extracting elements from xml files in python fails

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have a huge problem with my code and I hope someone can help out here. I need to extract a specific element out of xml files, which lay in multiple subdirectories. I wrote a script to go though all folders and subdirectories to get to the xml files and extract that one element and save it in a separate file. The code looks like this:

```
import os

import csv

import itertools

import pandas as pd

from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

path = "D:/..."

file = open('out.csv', 'w')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for filename in files:
        if not filename.endswith(".xml"): continue
        if filename.endswith(".xml"):
            fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
            tree = ET.parse(fullname)
            root = tree.getroot()
            for row in root.iter('p'):
                file.write(row.text)
```

The error I get is "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:/..\0000233.xml"

eventhough the file exists and has content.

What did I do wrong? I would be so thankfull for help and tipps as I am new to python.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't joining the correct parts of the file path together, you are only appending the `path` and the `filename`. If the xml file exists in a subdirectory of `path`, you won't find this file. Your current method will only work for files inside the folder specified by path.

The below method uses pathlib and it's `glob` method to search recursively for all xml files in the directory and subdirectories. This saves you from having to check each file to see if they have the `.xml` file extension as it will only return xml files. Pathlib also returns the absolute path of the file rather than having to join the different parts together.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

path = Path(r"C:\\Users\\MyFiles\\")

file = open('out.csv', 'w')
print(path)

for file_path in path.glob('**/*.xml'):
    try:
        tree = ET.parse(file_path)
        root = tree.getroot()
        for row in root.iter('p'):
            file.write(row.text)
            print(row.text)
    except ET.ParseError:
        print(f"Couldn't parse {file_path} - Ignoring")
```

Obviously you'll need to change the path to match where you want to search.

Comment: @kathi94 Welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer if it worked for you.